# Can we get email and password from authentication from Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

I want to get email and password after user signup in my Xamarin app, the question is can I get that email and password using this result and then  save it to my SQL database in Azure.

```cs
async void SignUp() {
    DisplayAlert("Result", "Cek Result ", "Ok");
    try {
        var result = await App.AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenAsync(
            Constants.Scopes,
            string.Empty,
            UiOptions.SelectAccount,
            string.Empty,
            null,
            Constants.Authority,
            Constants.SignUpPolicy);

    } catch (MsalException) {
        // Do nothing - ErrorCode will be displayed in OnLoginButtonClicked
    }
}
```

and I tried using `AuthenticationResult` to get user email and password, but I'm only can get user display name , can this `AuthenticationResult` get user email and password? Or is there any method that can do the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An application cannot get the password for security reasons. In the B2C Admin portal, you can select "emails" to be sent to the application in your policy. The email address used for signup will be in this claim when the token is issued.

You could create a user using AD Graph API and write the password in two places. But, if you are storing the password in any other store (e.g. SQL DB), you will also have to figure out how to keep them in sync when the user changes the password.

In addition, is the aspect of how to properly secure the passwords in the DB. One of the value propositions of a directory is to provide such a security layer.

If you update your question with the scenario you are trying to solve, may be there's a workaround that we could figure out.

Comment: ok in my signup policy claim i already claim the email to get the email data should i use graph api or can i use Microsoft.Identity.Client, but in microsoft identiy.Client  i only can get users name,authority, client id, unique id, identity provider and displayable id. Is it because im using microsoft.identy.client old version (1.0.304142221-alpha) or maybe it just cant get the email